# Why won't mathematica plot the 3D Contour of this function?

Tags: plotting

I want to find the 3D contour of the equation1:

```
C1 = 10^(-10);
C2 = 0.1*C1;
R = 50;
Tb = 0.1;
Geb = 5*10^-15;
Z0 = 50;
L[Te_] := 10^-9 + 10^-9*(Te - 0.1);
Zlcr[Te_, w_] := (1/R + 1/(I*L[Te]*w) + I*C1*w)^-1;
Zload[Te_, w_] := -I*w*C2 + Zlcr[Te, w];
\[CapitalGamma][Te_, w_] := (Zload[Te, w] - Z0)/(Zload[Te, w] + Z0);
y[Te_, w_] := (Abs[\[CapitalGamma][Te, w]])^2;
eqn1[w_, Te_, Pprobe_] := (1 -   y[Te, w]) Pprobe  ==  (Te - Tb) Geb
ContourPlot3D[
 eqn1[w, Te, Pprobe], {w, 0, 5*10^9}, {Te, 0, 1}, {Pprobe, 0, 10^-14}]
```

Comment: I don't understand this part: `==  (Te - Tb) Geb`! Why do use `==` inside definition of a function?

Comment: (Te-Tb)Geb is simply equal to (Te - 0.1)* (5*10^(-15))

Comment: Yes that is correct but I think this definition `(1 -   y[Te, w]) Pprobe  ==  (Te - Tb) Geb` is wrong. Are `(1 -   y[Te, w]) Pprobe` and  `(Te - Tb) Geb` equal?

Comment: Use `Evaluate[eqn1[w, Te, Pprobe]]` inside `ContourPlot3D`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your last function just to expression and evaluate in plot:

```
exp = (1 - y[Te, w]) Pprobe == (Te - Tb) Geb;
ContourPlot3D[
 Evaluate[exp], {w, 0, 5*10^9}, {Te, 0, 1}, {Pprobe, 0, 10^-14}, 
 Mesh -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, you are a master at graphics!